# Unable to install pods in outsystems environment using cordova plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, outsystems

I am working on cordova plugin , I have achieved functionality in native as well as cordova hybrid app for Android in Outsystems.
But When i am trying to generate build from Outsystems for iOS and installing application in iOS ,app gets crash .

**Native Code Link :** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kZrb80_sOdDytx34TPhH8MuSMX0ONyjA   (Working)

**Hybrid Code Link :** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dgUMzBNnZJxQ9bb28hUoI5Czm2K8VpDH  (Working)

**Cordova Plugin Code Link :** https://github.com/vviek/cordova-idnow-ios (Not Working with Outsystems)

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong in plugin .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be aware of which versions MABS uses to generate the apps. Check them here: https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Release_Notes/Mobile_Apps_Build_Service_Versions

Another thing is that MABS 6.1 does not work with use-frameworks. I recommend you to convert the CocoaPods dependencies to universal libraries. For that I recommend this awesome tool: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Rome

Hope this helps!